# Error: ambiguous column name during inner join / select

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with two tables. "Games" is table with all baseball games from a given season with various identifying info in columns like date, home team, visitor team, and so forth. "Special" is table with all games that have met a certain criteria, with only three columns. I want to select all rows from "Games" that match the three columns in "Special".

I have tried the code below but get "ambiguous column name" at the first criteria trying to match column data, specifically "main.Games.Date_of_Game" is cited as ambiguous? (but of course my code does not say "main.games.date_of_game" so?

```
SELECT games.* 
from games 
INNER join games on (Special.Date_of_Game=Games.Date_of_Game AND
games.home=Special.HomeTeam AND game.gamenumber=Special.GameNumber)
```

I want an output of all rows from "Games" that match all three columns from Special (which is a subset of "Games" selected from outside source but is formatted similar to the columns in Games).

Comment: You have a simple typo.  The table name is `games`, but one of the aliases is spelled `game` (without an `s`).  Also, you are referencing a table `Special` in the ON clause, but it is not referenced in the FROM clause.  It is worth taking errors literally sometimes... if it says there is an ambiguous name, then the first thing should be to double check all spellings and ensure that all named tables and columns are actually properly referenced in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join `Games` with `Games`, but as you say you want to join with the table `Special`:

```
SELECT Games.* 
from Games INNER join Special 
on 
  Special.Date_of_Game=Games.Date_of_Game 
  AND Games.home=Special.HomeTeam 
  AND Games.gamenumber=Special.GameNumber
```

Also you mispelled the table Games in the ON clause.

Comment: I can confirm that switching the Inner join to Special has enabled the search to function, but I do not understand why. . .

Comment: *I want an output of all rows from "Games" that match all three columns from Special* this is what you want. So you must join Games to Special.

Comment: @643gdp  If you still don't understand, then you may need to review a tutorial on SQL joins.  There are many tutorials and explanations if you perform a web search, but [here's one](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join) that seems to explain well.

Comment: Thank you! (I agree about the typo, but I did not find a tutorial for joins that gave me clues until now--all the best to you both!

Comment: See this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/ or this: https://mode.com/resources/sql-tutorial/sql-joins/